# Best way to deal with a message queue in Magento 1.x Custom Module

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, messages, queue

I have a situation where I need to process a request that will create a queue of messages to be sent, and I need this messages to be processed and send continuously.

The current solution I have in my mind is to **create a Magento cronjob** that will check every `n` minutes if my `script.php` is running.

If it's running, all good. If not, it will start running it, and this is script will have a **infinite loop** that process all messages on the queue.

I don't know why, but something in this solution sound sketchy to me, so I'd like to know if there's a better solution for that. I don't want to use **RabbitMQ** or other **linux-like** software.

EDIT: for a better context, I'm trying to guarantee messages are processed and sent in a personal chatbot project that integrate Magento to Facebook Messenger and Telegram (https://github.com/blopa/Magento-Chatbot/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not sound this bad. 
A cronjob is a good start. Instead of triggering a second script, you can do the processing as part of the cronjob.
The easiest is to limit the number of processed messages low enough, that it is finished before it is run the next time. Running it every 5min should be often enough for most cases.

If the limit is not possible, because it sometimes needs more time, or because you need to process as much messages as possible in one run, you can use some kind of locking mechanism.

[UPDATE]

ok, as I now know more about the scope, we need to think a bit bigger.
As you need a guarantee for messages to be processed you will need a queue  system. This can be RabbitMQ(which is the most stable and tested solution), this can also be Kafka(probably no, this is really to much), or my favorit as a first step, a simple queue table which consinsts of only the necessary collums. (mysql scales quite well in general)
The reason is, you must be able to split "accepting new messages" from processing them. The processing must be able to fail, without loosing the initiating message, so you are able to retry.
From experience I know, that some "requests" will need far more then just a few seconds to process, but you should be able to accept new requests from other users while processing a request.
Also, some Shops may want to scale the process up, because they have such a big audience, that a few 100 requests per minutes are not unlikely. Having a proper queue system allows to scale the processing part up.
This means, you should also use an additional queue to schedule the results for sending out.
Because the accepting/sending part is very hard to scale higher then 1 worker per chatservice.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @Flyingmana. I'll use that for a chatbot, so messages must be sent out as fast as possible, that's why I'm thinking about using a infinite loop script, to make sure all messages are going to be processed ASAP. The cronjob would be like a safety measure to make sure the script is always running. I don't want to use RabbitMQ or other linux-like softwares.

Comment: I see, that changes things a lot. What kind of Data do you need from magento, and how fast do you want responses to be? And are messages from users of interest?
Is connecting/disconnecting a noticable/annoying action visible for users?

Comment: There are plenty of different processes to be handled by Magento. Pretty much everything is written in here https://github.com/blopa/Magento-Chatbot/

Comment: This is a module developed by me, and currently it just get the messages request from client, process it, and respond, with no guarantee that that response will be sent if a exception occurs

Comment: That gives me a better scope, I will try to write an updated post, taking the special requirements into account it has as an openSource project

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope this matches better your requirements

Comment: Thank you very much @Flyingmana. Just to make things clear, you mean something like this:

https://i.imgur.com/BtzFXcS.jpg

1 - User send the message and that messages is saved on database. And that's it.
2 - A endless worker will consume all input messages and process them AND a endless worker will consume all output messages and send them back to the chat.

My main fear is, what happens if a worker fail in some random exception? How can I guarantee it will be up and running any given time? I'm afraid of that because I never trully worked with threads in PHP before.

Comment: to guarantee to have always a worker running is a complete different question, with a lot of possible solutions and own problems. Start either with a cronjob or a normal script you trigger via nohup or screen. When the project got more users, there will come someone with more experience/knowledge, and maybe even a good implementation.
But a normal php script runs without problems for months to years, I have one for irc which I only need to restart, when the server was rebootet